# ShellScript hex to decimal

Tags: android, shell

I have a file how capture the users events in a txt file :

```
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0039 0000001d
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0035 00000169
```

Now I would create a shell script how converts hex data to decimal for example I would like :

```
/dev/input/event2: 3 57 29
/dev/input/event2: 3 53 361
```

How can I process ? I have tried to read the file line by line and split the string but It doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `gawk`, you could do as following. `input.txt` is the file you capture the events.

```
$ awk '{printf "%s ", $1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){v="0x"$i;printf "%d ",strtonum(v)};printf "\n";}' input.txt 
/dev/input/event2: 3 57 29 
/dev/input/event2: 3 53 361
```

Comment: I have this error with your code : awk: line 2: function strtonum never defined